# "get_bucket_tagging" for s3 buckets give error, when there are no tags present

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to get S3 bucket tags using "get_bucket_tagging".

Code:

```
response = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket='bucket_name') 
print(response['TagSet'])
```

I am getting output till there are any tags present. But getting following error when there are 0 tags.

> An error occurred (NoSuchTagSet) when calling the GetBucketTagging
>   operation: The TagSet does not exist

Is there any other method to check that?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @Venkatesh
`response = client.get_bucket_tagging(
    Bucket='bucket_name'
)

    print(response['TagSet'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETtagging.html) document:

> NoSuchTagSetError - There is no tag set associated with the bucket.

So when there is no tag set associated with the bucket, error/exception is expected. You need to handle this exception.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

try:
    response = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket='bucket_name')
    print(response['TagSet'])

except Exception, e:
    # Handle exception
    # Do something
    print e
```

Comment: Catch only the NoSuchTagSet error with `if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchTagSet':`